# Detecting leaving usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, architecture, user-controls

I have a ListBox with my menu items in it.

```
 <ListBox x:Name="ListBoxMenu"  SelectionChanged="ListBoxMenu_SelectionChanged"             
                 Grid.Column="0" Margin="0" Padding="0" Grid.Row="1" Width="{StaticResource LeftMenuWidth}"                 
                 ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}"
                 Background="{StaticResource ListBoxColor}"
                 BorderThickness="0"
                 SelectedIndex="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DockPanel>
                        <Image Source="{Binding MenuImage}" Height="20" Width="20" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="5" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MenuName}" FontSize="{StaticResource MenuFontSize}" FontWeight="Bold" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    </DockPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

I *kind of chopped up the code hope it still make since.*

Then I have a control template that loads each user control.

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ElementName=ListBoxMenu, Path=SelectedItem}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

**The Problem:**

My problem is that I would like to test when a user leaves the user control if they have made any changes to ask them to save the changes.  I already have NotifyPropertyChange working so that isn't the problem.   I need to figure out how to see when the user is leaving the control / page.

**What I have tried**

As you can see I have added selectionchanged to the list box which technically does work however its not ideal because the usercontrol changes visually then the user is prompted to save any changes.  I want to prompt them before they leave the user control.

```
SelectionChanged="ListBoxMenu_SelectionChanged"
```

Comment: Tried LostFocus event?

Comment: Nope I am a little new to WPF, I will give this a try and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

**Updates #1**

There is more than one possible helpful suggestions to handle the "from view navigation", here are a couple of simple examples:

1. In order to check if your control is active(I mean is shown to user), when there is no any navigation controllers in use, I think you can use the control's IsVisibleChanged event that indicates the control's IsVisible(true/false) state. In case you want to start the IsDirty logic when your control is partially visible you can use the @Evk guy suggestion(using of LostFocus), test the IsHitTestVisible on the control bounds and according to the test result(how more the control is hidden) you can start(or not) your desired logic.

**Here is an example of IsHitTest visibilty([from this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517743/in-wpf-how-can-i-determine-whether-a-control-is-visible-to-the-user))**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// helps to indicate the partial IsVisible state
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="element">elemnt under the test</param>
    /// <param name="container">parent window or control</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private bool IsUserVisible(FrameworkElement element, FrameworkElement container)
    {
        if (!element.IsVisible)
            return false;

        Rect bounds = element.TransformToAncestor(container).TransformBounds(new Rect(0.0, 0.0, element.ActualWidth, element.ActualHeight));
        Rect rect = new Rect(0.0, 0.0, container.ActualWidth, container.ActualHeight);
        return rect.Contains(bounds.TopLeft) || rect.Contains(bounds.BottomRight);
    }
```

2. In case you have a navigation supporting control(something like a [Frame](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.frame(v=vs.110).aspx)) you can use its events to know that the navigation is started(aka you are going to move to another control), like [FragmentNavigation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.fragmentnavigation(v=vs.110).aspx).

In addition you should implement an IsDirty on your ViewModel. Here are a few examples of how to do that:

1. [MVVM - implementing 'IsDirty' functionality to a ModelView in order to save data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556387/mvvm-implementing-isdirty-functionality-to-a-modelview-in-order-to-save-data)
2. [Almost-automatic INotifyPropertyChanged, automatic IsDirty, and automatic ChangeTracking](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41791/Almost-automatic-INotifyPropertyChanged-automatic).

**Here is some code sample for an IsDirty implementation([all credit to this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890212/wpf-mvvm-how-to-detect-if-a-view-is-dirty))**

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides a base class for objects that support property change notification 
/// and querying for changes and resetting of the changed status.
/// </summary>
public abstract class ViewModelBase : IChangeTracking, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //========================================================
    //  Constructors
    //========================================================
    #region ViewModelBase()
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ViewModelBase"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    protected ViewModelBase()
    {
        this.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(OnNotifiedOfPropertyChanged);
    }
    #endregion

    //========================================================
    //  Private Methods
    //========================================================
    #region OnNotifiedOfPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the <see cref="INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged"/> event for this object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">A <see cref="PropertyChangedEventArgs"/> that contains the event data.</param>
    private void OnNotifiedOfPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e != null && !String.Equals(e.PropertyName, "IsChanged", StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            this.IsChanged = true;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    //========================================================
    //  IChangeTracking Implementation
    //========================================================
    #region IsChanged
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the object's changed status.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// <see langword="true"/> if the object’s content has changed since the last call to <see cref="AcceptChanges()"/>; otherwise, <see langword="false"/>. 
    /// The initial value is <see langword="false"/>.
    /// </value>
    public bool IsChanged
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_notifyingObjectIsChangedSyncRoot)
            {
                return _notifyingObjectIsChanged;
            }
        }

        protected set
        {
            lock (_notifyingObjectIsChangedSyncRoot)
            {
                if (!Boolean.Equals(_notifyingObjectIsChanged, value))
                {
                    _notifyingObjectIsChanged = value;

                    this.OnPropertyChanged("IsChanged");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private bool _notifyingObjectIsChanged;
    private readonly object _notifyingObjectIsChangedSyncRoot = new Object();
    #endregion

    #region AcceptChanges()
    /// <summary>
    /// Resets the object’s state to unchanged by accepting the modifications.
    /// </summary>
    public void AcceptChanges()
    {
        this.IsChanged = false;
    }
    #endregion

    //========================================================
    //  INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation
    //========================================================
    #region PropertyChanged
    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when a property value changes.
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    #endregion

    #region OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    /// <summary>
    /// Raises the <see cref="INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged"/> event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">A <see cref="PropertyChangedEventArgs"/> that provides data for the event.</param>
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    /// <summary>
    /// Raises the <see cref="INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged"/> event for the specified <paramref name="propertyName"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">The <see cref="MemberInfo.Name"/> of the property whose value has changed.</param>
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion

    #region OnPropertyChanged(params string[] propertyNames)
    /// <summary>
    /// Raises the <see cref="INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged"/> event for the specified <paramref name="propertyNames"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyNames">An <see cref="Array"/> of <see cref="String"/> objects that contains the names of the properties whose values have changed.</param>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">The <paramref name="propertyNames"/> is a <see langword="null"/> reference (Nothing in Visual Basic).</exception>
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(params string[] propertyNames)
    {
        if (propertyNames == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyNames");
        }

        foreach (var propertyName in propertyNames)
        {
            this.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Let me know if you want more examples or code.

Comment: Thank you I can detect isdirty on my view model already but I can't test it before the user navigates from the user control. Also link only anwsers are not optimal

Comment: @DaImTo and thanks for your comment I'm very appreciate that